# AWS Cognito Identity: Why do I get 403 Forbidden when invoking API Gateway with iam_role authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I have a simple serverless.yml as follows:

```
service: test-lambda
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
          authorizer: aws_iam
```

I also have configured AWS Cognito User Pool, APP Client and Identity Pool.

Both my authenticated and unauthenticated roles have the following IAM Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": "*",
       "Resource": "*"
     }
   ]
```

However, when I make a request to my API using the [aws-api-gateway-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client):

```
apig-test \
--username='sls@test.com' \
--password='Passw0rd!' \
--user-pool-id='us-east-1_Fmws96qkp' \
--app-client-id='75ujpfhk63kt39tb0hmplpddr3' \
--cognito-region='us-east-1' \
--identity-pool-id='us-east-1:addcched-eb42-4802-817f-700f13e51d8e' \
--invoke-url='https://28p4ir5tx8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev' \
--api-gateway-region='us-east-1' \
--path-template='/hello' \
--method='GET'
```

I keep getting:

```
Autheticating with User Pool
Getting temporary credentials
Making API Request
status: 403, statusText: Forbidden
```

**Note** All credentials and IAM Policies listed in the question are hypothetical.

Comment: be careful when exposing your API Gateway's endpoint like that. Remember that you pay for million requests and if somebody runs a script against this endpoint you won't be too happy with the outcome I am sure. (I tested it against your URL and this is a valid one, so I suggest you delete this API Gateway and create a new one)

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Hi Thales. Thanks for pointing this out! The credentials listed here are from a blog post that I was following and I assumed that they have also put in fake credentials, but since you tested it out and concluded that they are real this could have escalated into a problem for that person. I changed them now. Thanks!

Comment: My point was not the credentials but API gateway's endpoint instead. `https://28p4ir5tx8.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/hello` is a valid endpoint and requests to this address will be accounted even if they are returning 403.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi Yes, that is what I understood from your response as well. It has been changed to a non-existing endpoint.